# Eclipe Mars, PDT. Disable formatter forever

Tags: eclipse-pdt

PHP formatter makes annoying mistakes. For example, sets up to 8 spaces, where expects only 4. It is realy boring. I better formatting code manualy. So, how to switch off this feature in global context?

Answer (score 0):

What you mean? Indentation adjusting while writing or ctrl+shift+f? If ctrl+shift+f just stop using it :P

If auto adjust, Preferences / PHP / Editor / Typing.

But probably better will be change indentation size in php formatter profile at Preferences / PHP / Code Style / Formatter. (Preferences / Web /HTML Files / Editor - to change tab size).

Anyway you probably should report a bug: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=PDT

Comment: I mean exacly Code Style / Formatter. I set off everything, what is possible there, but some formatting still applied, when typing. Eventually I decided my problem - gone to PhpStorm. It is much better IDE, more predictably and obvious.

Comment: To disable formatting while typing you have to disable auto adjust.

Comment: In that way I have no indentation ever. But I want just correct indentation. I know, that it come from formatter, _Indentation size_ adds to smart indent. And if set it to 0, I got another bug: tabs instead spaces in indentation.